# Joining three tables. Two related, and one unrelated to the other two

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

I want to Create a view called ShowAllBooksBorrowed that shows the information (BookName, ISBN, BookCategoryName, BookAuthor, BorrowedDate, ReturnDate, ActualReturnDate) of all the books that have been borrowed from the library but not returned.

I am having trouble figuring out how to relate the BorrowerInfo table to the BookInfo and BookCategory table using the information from the Books table. I understand how it relates but I am not sure how to carry this out. I think I may need to use Union or CrossJoin?

here is my database:
[image: Library Database]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much point showing the `ActualReturnDate` if the book has not actually been returned.

Comment: Tables (bases, views & query results) represent relation(ship)s/associations. FKs are sometimes called "relationships" but they are not; they say that subrows appear elsewhere. Table meanings are necessary & sufficient to query. Constraints--including CKs, PKs & FKs-- are not needed to query. They are consequences of the table relation(ship)/association choices & what situations/states can arise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a view like as shown below:

```
create view show_all_books_borrowed as 
select
  k.bookname,
  b.isbn,
  c.bookcategoryname,
  k.bookauthor, 
  w.borrowdate, 
  w.returndate, 
  w.actualreturndate
from books b
join borrowerinfo w on w.bookid = b.bookid
join bookinfo k on k.isbn = b.isbn
join bookcategory c on k.bookcategoryid = c.bookcategoryid
where w.actualreturndate is null
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick! I knew I was going to have a "DUH" moment after I saw the code.